# Как пропарсить ссылку на определеное содержание?

Tags: php, парсер

Добрый день.

Помогите реализовать такую задачу. Необходимо перейти по внешней ссылке, найти там определенный текст и если он там есть, выполнить действие, если нет, то взять другую ссылку. Ссылки в базе.

Я только учусь php и не знаю, как сделать, чтобы он по определенной ссылке искал определенный текст.

Comment: Хотя-бы пример покажите.

Answer (score 1):

Вам скорее всего необходимы Регулярные выражения. 
[Тут можете почитать](http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/preg.php).

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм действий

1. Подключаетесь к Базе.
2. Достаете все ссылки и с каждой в цикле работаете

ЦИКЛ:

1. С помощью библиотеки cURL загружаете страницу.
2. С помощью регулярок или функций работы со строками (они быстрее регулярок) определяете есть необходимая инфа или нет. В зависимости от результата - выполняетет функцию.

Но для новичка это будет сложно

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Ale_x. В тот же день сделал.
Вот только проверить работоспособность смог через сутки. Сайт который парсил я, заблокировал ip моего сервера.
Блокирует уже на 3-й ссылки :(
Извините что под новым логином, почту украли.

```
<?php
include_once('configuration.php');
$link = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqllogin, $mysqlpass);
if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error().'<br />');
}
echo 'Успешно соединились'.'<br />';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('xmlfind5', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Не удалось выбрать базу xmlfind5: ' . mysql_error().'<br />');
}

echo " Выбрали базу <br />";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM xml";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        if ($i<1800994){
        $text = file_get_contents($row["2"]);
                if (preg_match( '/<title>(удалена страничка)<\/title>/    is' , $text , $title )){
            echo $row["2"]."<br>";
            $query = 'DELETE FROM xml WHERE id IN ('.$row["0"].')';
            mysql_query( $query );  
            }
        $i++;
        }
    }
    echo "Всего проверил: $i"."<br>";
?>
```